# Thousand separator in script file

Tags: javascript

This is my code to render an auto increment counter on my page:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var START_DATE_1 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL_1 = 3; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
    var count_1 = 0;

    var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1000;
    var now_1 = new Date();
    count_1 = parseInt((now_1 - START_DATE_1)/msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;
    document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    setInterval(function() {
      count_1 += INCREMENT_1;
      document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    }, msInterval_1);
  });
</script>
```

I would like to render the numbers of the counter with thousand separator (example: 2.000.000)

How should I edit the script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `count_1.toLocaleString()` works in most browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern browsers you can use the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

> The Intl object is the namespace for the ECMAScript
>   Internationalization API, which provides language sensitive string
>   comparison, number formatting, and date and time formatting. The
>   constructors for Collator, NumberFormat, and DateTimeFormat objects
>   are properties of the Intl object. This page documents these
>   properties as well as functionality common to the internationalization
>   constructors and other language sensitive functions.

I'm using Italian in the following example, just based on your name and it uses your required format.

```js
var START_DATE_1 = new Date('July 18, 2016 10:30:00').getTime(); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL_1 = 3; // in seconds
var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1000;
var now_1 = Date.now();
var count_1 = Math.trunc((now_1 - START_DATE_1) / msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;

function formatNumber(number) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('it').format(number);
}

document.getElementById('counter_1').textContent = formatNumber(count_1);
setInterval(function() {
  count_1 += INCREMENT_1;
  document.getElementById('counter_1').textContent = formatNumber(count_1);
}, msInterval_1);
```

```html
<pre id="counter_1"></pre>
```